# regarding understanding supporting different screen sizes

Tags: android

i referred to a website to know how to create different layout folders to support different screen size.
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/different-layouts-for-different-screen-sizes-in-android/

in the aforementioned link states the following :

```
res/layout-sw320dp : Devices with a smallest screen width which is greater than 320dp will make use the layouts defined in this folder

res/layout-sw480dp: Devices with a smallest screen width which is greater than 480dp will make use the layouts defined in this folder
```

my question is, what if there is a devie with screen width of 500dp for exampl, then which folder will be used 'res/layout-sw320dp' or 'res/layout-sw480dp'?

Answer (score 3):

In the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), under *Provide different layouts for different screen sizes*, you can read:

> By default, Android resizes your application layout to fit the current
> device screen. In most cases, this works fine. In other cases, your UI
> might not look as good and might need adjustments for different screen
> sizes. For example, on a larger screen, you might want to adjust the
> position and size of some elements to take advantage of the additional
> screen space, or on a smaller screen, you might need to adjust sizes
> so that everything can fit on the screen.
>
> The configuration qualifiers
> you can use to provide size-specific resources are small, normal,
> large, and xlarge. For example, layouts for an extra-large screen
> should go in layout-xlarge/.
>
> **Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level
> 13), the above size groups are deprecated and you should instead use
> the swdp configuration qualifier to define the smallest available
> width required by your layout resources. For example, if your
> multi-pane tablet layout requires at least 600dp of screen width, you
> should place it in layout-sw600dp/.**

<sub>Emphasis mine.</sub>

and further down, under *Using new size qualifiers*:

> For example, if your layout requires that its smallest dimension of
> screen area be at least 600 dp at all times, then you can use this
> qualifier to create the layout resources, res/layout-sw600dp/. **The
> system will use these resources only when the smallest dimension of
> available screen is at least 600dp**, regardless of whether the 600dp
> side is the user-perceived height or width.

<sub>Emphasis mine.</sub>

What this means that if you have a sw320dp and a sw480dp folder, a device with a screen width of 500dp will use the sw480dp folder.

A device with a screen width of 479dp will use the sw320dp folder.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you read the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)?

There, in the examples, you can see:

> For other cases in which you want to further customize your UI to differentiate between sizes such as 7” and 10” tablets, you can define additional smallest width layouts:
>
> res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
>
> res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
>
> res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)

From this you can clearly see that a device with more than 720dp will not use the 600dp files.

So in your example the answer would be the 'res/layout-sw480dp' folder.